# NoReverseMatch error in Django pagination

Tags: regex, django, pagination, slug

The slug name pattern matches for the first page of pagination but it returns 'NoReverseMatch' error for other pages.

This is the template:

```
added by <a href="{% url 'pplistPage' story.author %}"><strong>{{ story.author }}</strong></a>
```

This is the urls.py (I've tried many other regex, still same problem)

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<profile>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/', views.profilepostlist, name='pplistPage'),
```

this is the views.py

```
def homepage(request, latest_f=latest_f, latest_m=latest_m, latest_a=latest_a, ppp=ppp):

stories = Story.objects.all().order_by("-modified")

paginator = Paginator(stories, ppp)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    story_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    story_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    story_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    'stories' : story_list,
    'latest_f' : latest_f,
    'latest_m' : latest_m,
    'latest_a' : latest_a,
}

return render(request, 'listing/index.html', context)
```

Weird thing is it works in the first page of pagination and in index page and even in the story page which does not have pagination. But when I click the other pages ( '127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2' ) it raises the error.

Example pattern: `127.0.0.1:8000/profile/orhan/`

Error message:

```
Reverse for 'pplistPage' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<profile>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/']'
```

Comment: The `'('',)'` shows that `story.author` is being evaluated as an empty string. That means that either `story` does not exist on the page where you get the error, or you have a story where the author evaluates to the empty string. You can debug by removing the url tag for now and trying `{{ story }}` and `{{ story.author }}`.

Comment: But when i remove the regex link, <strong>{{ story.author }}</strong> part is being eveluated perfectly. (by the way, there is only one author -orhan- for every story)

Comment: Check that `{{ story.author }}` is working for *every* story on the page. It might be evaluated perfectly for some stories, but it looks like there is at least one where it isn't.

Comment: I am ashamed of myself, you were right. There is a post which doesn't have an author. That is why it raises the error.

Comment: No need to feel ashamed, glad you found the problem :)